# Mvoing DbContext in a separate class with a different project cause exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I am using Entity Framework for my DAL (using DBContext). The layered architecture we are following in big on separation of concern and for this purpose, the entity class that get generated has to go in separate class project. Since program has to be unit-testable, I am using Repository pattern and for that reason I need to abstract the DbContext that we get from EF. All this mean that the entity class and context class is not in the same project where my edmx file lives. Problem is when I move the files around, I start getting following exception

> Unhandled Exception: System.Data.MetadataException: Unable to load the
>   specified  metadata resource.    at
>   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoaderCompositeResource.LoadResou
>   rces(String assemblyName, String resourceName, ICollection`1
>   uriRegistry, Metada taArtifactAssemblyResolver resolver)    at
>
>   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoaderCompositeResource..ctor(Str
>   ing originalPath, String assemblyName, String resourceName,
>   ICollection`1 uriReg istry, MetadataArtifactAssemblyResolver resolver)
>   at
>   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoaderCompositeResource.CreateRes
>   ourceLoader(String path, ExtensionCheck extensionCheck, String
>   validExtension, I Collection`1 uriRegistry,
>   MetadataArtifactAssemblyResolver resolver)    at
>
>   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoader.Create(String path,
>   Extens ionCheck extensionCheck, String validExtension, ICollection`1
>   uriRegistry, Metad ataArtifactAssemblyResolver resolver)    at
>   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.SplitPaths(String paths)    at
>   System.Data.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.<>c__DisplayClass2.<Evaluate>b__0()
>   at System.Data.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.Result.GetValue()    at
>   System.Data.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.Evaluate(TArg arg)    at
>
>   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetMetadataWorkspace(Boolean
>   ini tializeAllCollections)    at
>
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.RetrieveMetadataWorkspaceFromConnection(
>   )    at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor(EntityConnection
>   connection, Boole an isConnectionConstructor)    at
>
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor(EntityConnection connection)
>
>   at
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalConnection.CreateObjectContextFromConn
>   ectionModel()    at
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.CreateObjectContextFrom
>   ConnectionModel()    at
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
>
>   at
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType
>   (Type entityType)    at
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
>
>   at
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Pro
>   vider()    at System.Linq.Queryable.Where[TSource](IQueryable`1
>   source, Expression`1 pre dicate)    at
>   BusinessLayer.CustomerLocator.LocateCustomerByIdint id) in
>   C:\Sandbox\BusinessLayer\CustomerLocator.cs:line 41    at
>   ClientApp.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Sandbox\ Program.cs:line
>   34

Googling suggest that there could be something wrong regarding paths to csdl, ssdsl etc but I am not sure what is wrong here. Below is how my connection string is been setup

```
<add name="DBConnection" 
   connectionString="metadata=res://*/MyDataModel.csdl|res://*/MyDataModel.ssdl|res://*/MyDataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;initial catalog=Customers;persist security info=True;user id=user;password=password;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: Moving the entity classes is probably not the problem. But why do you move the context class into another project than the EDMX file? I'd say context and EDMX are NOT separate concerns.

Comment: Because If I want to test against mock, that mean I will have to abstract DbContext so that it can talk to DB (using EF) or to my mocked data. There may be some better way of doing it but I just don't know that.

Comment: OK, the abstract context might be in another assembly but what forces you to move the concrete EF `DbContext` to the same assembly as well?

Comment: I think you gave me food for thought :) I need to go back on drawing board. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think it's better to keep concrete `DbContext` and EDMX in the same assembly. But if that's not possible for you for some reason you can take a look here: http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/08/13/38628/ It seems possible to replace the `*` in the connection string's metadata section by a concrete assembly name to tell EF where to search for the EDMX.